Quickly training multiple small neural networks
I want to train multiple models on the same training data (just different initializations). Each model has exactly the same architecture. Crucially, the models are extremely small, so having them all in memory at the same time won't be a problem. How can I make this as efficient as possible?
I read that cuda is supposed to be non-blocking, so computations should be parallelized automatically. However, when I write the code in a naive way, I can see that the training time scales linearly with the number of models.
import time
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, network_size):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, network_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(network_size, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(self.fc1(x)))

def train(num_networks, network_size, num_iterations):
    criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
    data = torch.zeros((5, 2), device='cuda')
    targets = torch.ones((5, 1), device='cuda')
    
    models = []
    for _ in range(num_networks):
        models.append(MLP(network_size).cuda())
    for model in models:
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
        for _ in range(num_iterations):
            output = model(data)
            loss = criterion(output, targets)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

training_start = time.perf_counter()
train(1, 20, 1000)
print(f"Training 1 model took {time.perf_counter() - training_start:.2f}s")

training_start = time.perf_counter()
train(5, 20, 1000)
print(f"Training 5 models took {time.perf_counter() - training_start:.2f}s")

training_start = time.perf_counter()
train(15, 20, 1000)
print(f"Training 15 models took {time.perf_counter() - training_start:.2f}s")

Output:
Training 1 model took 0.68s
Training 5 models took 3.36s
Training 15 models took 10.18s

I've been able to optimize this by merging the models into one larger network architecture:
class MergedMLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_networks, network_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, num_networks * network_size, device='cuda')
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(num_networks * network_size, num_networks, device='cuda')
        
        self.fc2_weight_mask = torch.zeros_like(self.fc2.weight.data, device='cuda', requires_grad=False)
        for i in range(num_networks):
            self.fc2_weight_mask[i,i*network_size:(i+1)*network_size] = 1
        self.fc2.weight.data *= self.fc2_weight_mask

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(self.fc1(x)))
    
def train_merged(num_networks, network_size, num_iterations):
    criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
    data = torch.zeros((5, 2), device='cuda')
    targets = torch.ones((5, num_networks), device='cuda')
    
    model = MergedMLP(num_networks, network_size).cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        model.fc2.weight.grad *= model.fc2_weight_mask
        optimizer.step()
        
training_start = time.perf_counter()
train_merged(15, 20, 1000)
print(f"Training merged models took {time.perf_counter() - training_start:.2f}s")

Output:
Training merged models took 0.70s

Is it possible to achieve the runtime of the merged implementation with code more similar to the naive one? The merged implementation seems to be more error prone, e.g. when I increase the network size or want to extract individual networks from the trained merged model.

But those calls to fc1 and fc2 are independent of each other, so I was hoping they'd be executed in parallel. This was based on e.g. this discussion: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/train-two-or-more-neural-networks-parallel/132957

torch.multiprocessing does exactly what you need. You can rewrite the train function to the below:
def inner_train(model, optimizer, num_iterations, criterion, data, targets):
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        output = model(data) 
        loss = criterion(output, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
def train(num_networks, network_size, num_iterations):
    criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
    data = torch.zeros((5, 2), device='cuda')
    targets = torch.ones((5, 1), device='cuda')
    
    models = []
    optimizers = []
    for _ in range(num_networks):
        model = MLP(network_size).cuda()
        models.append(model)

        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
        optimizers.append(optimizer)

    num_processes = num_networks
    processes = []
    for model, optimizer in zip(models, optimizers):
        p = mp.Process(target=inner_train, args=(model, optimizer, num_iterations, criterion, data, targets,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

The output time should looks something like this:
Training 1 model took 0.07s
Training 5 models took 0.31s
Training 15 models took 0.88s


When I run this, I get 4.6s for 5, and 7.8s for 15 models. At least one second of each process is spent loading the torch libraries. I'm not sure where the rest of the time is lost. I've used your exact code, and guarded the call to train by if __name__ == '__main__': I've also set mp.set_start_method('forkserver')

The result above is the result I run in a notebook environment. I have tested it again on a     runtime environment and got ~4.6s through out. Seem like multiprocessing behaviours differ between notebook and runtime environment.

here is a fix for you train function. Idea is to do single backward pass for all models in one go. However there still will be some delays in execution because cuda is synchronizing with the python thread after calling each model.

class AllModels(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_models, network_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.models = nn.ModuleList()
        for _ in range(n_models):
          model = MLP(network_size)
          self.models.append(model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.concat([model.forward(x) for model in self.models])


def train(num_networks, network_size, num_iterations):
    criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
    data = torch.zeros((5, 2), device='cuda')
    targets = torch.ones((5, 1), device='cuda')

    model = AllModels(num_networks, network_size).cuda()

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
      loss = 0
      output = model(data)
      loss = criterion(output, targets.repeat(num_networks, 1))
      loss.backward() # 3.29
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      optimizer.step() #0.097



Thanks! That reduces the runtime to about 5 seconds on 15 models. So it's better than the original implementation, but still nowhere near the merged one. I was hoping cuda/PyTorch could automatically merge the separate forward/backward calls to the various networks.

Updated my answer and slightly improved performance.
